# multidimensional array to JSON return NULL in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an array, i want to convert this to json, but it returns null for a field,
here is my array:

```
 [workname] => IŞIKLAR MÜHENDİSLİK
 [workno] => 22330
 [workdate] => Array
    (
     [0] => Array
        (
         [date] => 
         [type] => ELEKTRİK
        )

     [1] => Array
        (
         [date] => 31.12.2007
         [type] => ELEKTRİK
        )
    )
```

when i convert this to json, i get workdate element as null.

```
{"workname":"IŞIKLAR MÜHENDİSLİK","workno":"22330","workdate":null}
```

Comment: I figure out that, its because im using array_map function with htmlentities callback. i have to use this for non english chars

Comment: Provide the following callback: `function($v){return htmlentities($v,ENT_DISALLOWED,'<your file encoding>');}` and your problem might be solved. Your encoding can be easily found using Notepad++ or (if you are on linux) using geany or similars (Sublime 2 isn't that good with encodings).

Answer (score 0):

```
 $arr = array('workname' => 'IŞIKLAR MÜHENDİSLİK','workno' => 22330,'workdate' => array('0' => array('date' => '','type' => 'ELEKTRİK'),'1' => array('date' => '31.12.2007','type' => 'ELEKTRİK')));

echo json_encode($arr);
```

outputs

```
{"workname":"I\u015eIKLAR M\u00dcHEND\u0130SL\u0130K","workno":22330,"workdate":[{"date":"","type":"ELEKTR\u0130K"},{"date":"31.12.2007","type":"ELEKTR\u0130K"}]}
```

you can check it here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68c91d260a0a18d584dab871f56dd7c97482ca04

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr=array(
    'workname' => 'IŞIKLAR MÜHENDİSLİK',
    'workno' => 22330,
    'workdate' => Array (
        Array (
            'date' => '',
            'type' => 'ELEKTRİK'
       ), 
       Array(
           'date' => '31.12.2007',
           'type' => 'ELEKTRİK'
       )
    )
);    
echo json_encode($arr);
```